# Как удалить лишние JDK?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

При создании проекта мне предлагается выбрать один из SDK

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть на моем компьютере 3 одинаковых JDK. Как поудалять лишние? Может есть какие-то команды, чтобы найти их путь хранения.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java

Comment: @FirstSin у меня не такой папки

Answer (score 1):

1. Нажимаешь на Add JDK
2. В открывшимся окне нажимаешь на значок на котором нарисован плюс и чашка как на 1 рис.
3. И нажимаешь на любую появившимся JDK после этого сома программа покажет где JDK расположен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]